# Condition in PowerShell script that read log files

Tags: powershell

I run .bat scripts from Task Scheduler and for each create a .log file.
In the log file, I can see whether or not the .bat script ended successfully. So far I have this basic script below that checks if the string 'Finished with errors' is in the .log files :

- YES -> FAILED
- NO -> SUCCESS

  Get-ChildItem C:\datalogs*.log | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] @{
  Name = $*.Name
  Date = $*.LastWriteTime
  Status =
  ('SUCCESS', 'FAILED')[(Select-String -Quiet 'Finished with errors' $_.FullName)]
  }
  }

I would like to be more subtle about the monitoring I do, by adding some conditions:
If in the .log file I have :

- 'Finished.' -> return **SUCCESS**
- 'Finished with errors' -> return **FAILED**
- 'Finished with warning' -> return **WARNING**
- String 'Finished' not in .log file -> return **FAILED**

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Get-Status($file) {
    if (Select-String -Quiet 'Finished with errors' $file) {
        return "FAILED"
    } elseif (Select-String -Quiet 'Finished with warning' $file) {
        return "WARNING"
    } elseif (Select-String -Quiet 'Finished' $file) {
        return "SUCCESS"
    } else {
       return "FAILED"
    }
}

Get-ChildItem C:\datalogs*.log | % { 
    [PSCustomObject] @{ 
        Name = $_.Name; 
        Date = $_.LastWriteTime; 
        Status = Get-Status($_.FullName)
    } 
}
```